# add exported data from console to csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server

I have script to export users and groups name from active directory to powershell console. Data is exported and it is ok, but Now, I need to add them from console to csv file with columns: Group Name and Users.

Please check below code:

```
$groups = "first_group","second_group"
 ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
     Get-ADGroupMember -identity $group | 
         Get-ADUser -properties displayName | 
             Select-Object SamAccountName, displayName, @{name="group";expression={$group}}
 }
```

Please assist to solve it.

Comment: $data | export-csv c:\temp\data.csv

Comment: @KemalK. I have added my code to question, can you please check it and send bak ready version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this **

```
$groups = "first_group","second_group"
$Table = @() 
$Record = @{
  "Group Name" = ""
  "Name"       = ""
  "Username"   = ""
}
Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
  $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group -recursive | select name, samaccountname
  foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
    $Record."Group Name" = $Group
    $Record."Name" = $Member.name
    $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
    $Table += $objrecord
  }
}
$Table
$Table | export-csv "C:\Temp\Group.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

`
this is the update for distinguishedname

```
    $Record = @{
  "Group Name" = ""
  "Name"       = ""
  "Username"   = ""
  "Group distinguishedName"=""
}
Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
  $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group -recursive | select name, samaccountname
    
  foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
    $Record."Group Name" = $Group
    $Record."Group distinguishedName" = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).DistinguishedName 
    $Record."Name" = $Member.name
    $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
    $Table += $objrecord
  }
}
```

Comment: K, Thank you very much, Kemal. Can you please help me to get full path name where is this group located

Comment: K, Thank you Kemal, buy when execute this script nothing happens, I mean I can not see path of the security group in my csv file. Can you please assist?

Comment: @TamerlanImanov  you need to delete old csv file before the run new script . can you show your script again.